# How to display SQL data in HTML as a table with AJAX JQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have some data stored in SQL file and want to display the data on HTML as a table with AJAX JQuery. The data comes out fine when I inspect it, but I am confused how I can display the data in HTML. Everything is a new concept to me and I'm having trouble finding the right way to do it. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>MySQL Employees </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p id = "data"></p>
    </div>
    <div id = "employee">
        <i>RECORDS PLACED HERE</i>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

AJAX Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax-GET-Employee",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {

            console.log("Returning MySQL data", data);
            // YOUR CODE GOES HERE

            for(let i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
                let employee = data.rows[i];
                console.log(employee.first_name, employee.last_name, employee.employee_id, employee.phone_number, employee.workstation, employee.security_level, employee.work_experience, employee.sales_record, employee.work_hour, employee.gender);
            }
            var div = $("data");
            div.html(data);
        },
        
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#data").text(textStatus + " " + errorThrown
                + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });

});
```

SQL

```
create table employee (
  ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name varchar(100),
  last_name varchar(100),
  employee_id varchar(100),
  phone_number varchar(100),
  workstation varchar(100),
  security_level varchar(100),
  work_experience varchar(100),
  sales_record varchar(100),
  work_hour varchar(100),
  gender varchar(100),

  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

insert into employee (first_name, last_name, employee_id, phone_number, workstation, security_level, work_experience, sales_record, work_hour, gender) values ('michael',  'jackson', '12321', '778223123', 'West Wing','Level 3', '5 years', '240 sales/month', '8AM-5PM', 'male');
insert into employee (first_name, last_name, employee_id, phone_number, workstation, security_level, work_experience, sales_record, work_hour, gender) values ('jason',  'ahn', '32183', '2364382954', 'North-South Wing','Level 1', '2 years', '80 sales/month', '8AM-4PM', 'male');
```

Back-end JS

```
// REQUIRES
const express = require('express');
// as of Express 4, you need this:
const app = express();
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const fs = require("fs");
// npm install mysql
const mysql = require('mysql');

app.use('/js', express.static('static/js'));
app.use('/css', express.static('static/css'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    let doc = fs.readFileSync('./static/html/main.html', "utf8");


    // leaving this in there so that you can see the opportunity to
    // change the document via jQuery - on the server side!
    //console.log(JSDOM);
    let dom = new JSDOM(doc);
    //let $ = require("jquery")(dom.window);
    //$("#p1").html("hello world!");

    res.send(dom.serialize());
});

app.get('/ajax-GET-Employee', function (req, res) {
    //set header to JSON type
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'root',
      password : '',
      database : 'test'
    });
    connection.connect();

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM employee', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      console.log('Rows returned are: ', results);
      res.send({ msg: "success", rows: results });

    });
    connection.end();

    // set the type of response:
    //res.send({ msg: "No data!" });

});


// for page not found (i.e., 404)
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).send("<html><head><title>Page cannot be found.</title></head><body><p>Nothing goes here.</p></body></html>");
})

// RUN SERVER
let port = 8000;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port ' + port + '!');
})
```

Comment: you are missing your back-end code where you basically do the SQL calls, make objects out of the results and send them as JSON back to the client.

In other words, the code between the AJAX request and the database

Comment: @FCR Don't see why that is relevant when OP has stated the data arrives fine. Question is how to parse it into DOM elements. No need to ask for code not relevant to the situation

Answer (score 0):

First you need to do you back end code it can be with PHP, Nodejs , python , etc.

Assuming that you have one , you can return your data as JSON.

Here is a very basic example that can help you to start:

```
  const jsonData = [
  {
    first_name: "michael",
    last_name: "jackson"
  },
  {
    first_name: "jason",
    last_name: "ahn"
  }
];

var list = "<table border='1'>";

$.each(jsonData, function (index, value) {
  list += "<tr >";
  list += "<td>" + value.first_name + "</td>";
  list += "<td>" + value.last_name + "</td>";
  list += "</tr>";
});

list += "</table>";

$("#app").html(list);
```

[Image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYOJ3.jpg)

Comment: Instead of writing const jsonData, is there any way to retrieve the data from sql file directly? I have edited my question by adding in the back-end JS code.

Comment: yes, just replace the jsonData  from you API return data, if you put and example of your API return data I can helo you with and example